# How can I watch a video in a Chrome tab?

Tags: video, google-chrome-extensions

I want to be able to flip between tabs whilst browsing the web and swap to a tab in Chrome where I have a video (I'm using VLC atm) playing from my hard drive.

Is this possible? I'm not even sure what to google to research this properly. If it is possible, how do I do it? If it helps I'm on Ubuntu.

### Edit:

I've just browsed the Chrome Web Store and I haven't found anything. Is this even possible?

I currently have this code running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<H1>Videos</H1>
<hr/>
<a href="Video.avi">Play Video name</a href><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

This *works* but it's not great as I'd like to have options of going back to the other videos. As it is this sounds more an more like a coding project not a 'find the right app' project. So I might have to just stop looking here, but if anything WebAppy turns up I'll be awarding the bounty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own HTML5 page: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I get support for AVIs?

Comment: I found that these don't work, but just putting in a link does, and it's full screen as I want. Is there a 'better' way to do this?

Comment: How do you define "better"?  This is just for your own personal viewing, right?  ...or are you working on a public web site/app?

Comment: Nick, It's just for me. I'd like to eventually keep the 'links' as I have them next to the `<video>` object, so getting an avi files to work in one of those would be better, I think. As it is I can't hit delete to go back the other links, and basic stuff like that.

Comment: What if you had 2 frames on your page - a "links" pane at the top/side/bottom and a larger pane for the video, updating your links: <code>&lt;a href="Video.avi" target="video">Play Video name&lt;/a href></code>

Comment: I could try and figure out how to do that. Though... I thought frames were the devil?

Comment: iframe might be nicer - especially if you could get it to disappear a few seconds after the mouse stopped moving over it.